# Print Screen PDF file with vba

Tags: vba, pdf

I want to open a PDF file and print the subaddress that i specified, but when i use Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})" just print screen Userform. My issue is how print screen just subaddress Rating Changes.

```
enter code here
Private Sub AlteraRating_Click()
Dim strFolde As String, Month As String, Year As String, strFile As String

Month = Format(SalvaData, "mm")
Year = Format(SalvaData, "yyyy")
pdfData = Format(SalvaData, "yyyymmdd")
strFolder = "C:\Report\Report of Investments\" & Year & "\" & Month & "\"


strFile = strFolder & "RAI_INFRAPREV PLANO CV_F03148_" & pdfData & ".pdf"
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strFile, "Rating Changes"

Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"
DoEvents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code in order to open the PDF, `FollowHyperlink` won't keep it open long enough to print screen.

```
Dim shell As Object
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34), 1, False
```